# Validation for seaching arrayLists

Tags: java, validation, search, arraylist

Hi i have created code that searches through an array list, i need to be able to print a line if nothing was found here is what ive have got.

```
            for (int i = 0; i < trackNum.size(); i++) { //looping arrayList trackNum
            if(trackNum.get(i).equals(trackNumber)){ //searching for matches to trackNumber
                System.out.println(trackNum.get(i) + ": " + name.get(i) + " " + duration.get(i)); //printing out the matches            
            } else{
                System.out.println("Not Tracks Found for " + trackNumber);
            }
        }
```

At the moment it doesn't print out the else line, it just stays blank.

Comment: Are you sure this is the code that matches your question? Because it seems to me that it should display the `else` part for each of the items in the list instead of just once, which is a different problem from the one you stated. If it stays blank, I believe the list is simply empty.

Comment: For example, you could write a function for iterating the tracks and return when something was found. The code after the loop gets executed only if the function didn't return, so you could output the not found message at that point.

You wouldn't need a loop if you used a hash map, though.

Answer (score 1):

You should only print the "Not found" message after iterating over the entire list :

```
        boolean found = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < trackNum.size(); i++) { //looping arrayList trackNum
            if(trackNum.get(i).equals(trackNumber)){ //searching for matches to trackNumber
                System.out.println(trackNum.get(i) + ": " + name.get(i) + " " + duration.get(i)); //printing out the matches            
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }   
        if (!found) {
            System.out.println("Not Tracks Found for " + trackNumber);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use `contains` and `indexOf` for such search:

```
    if (trackNum.contains(trackNumber)) {
        int i = trackNum.indexOf(trackNumber);
        System.out.println(trackNum.get(i) + ": " + name.get(i) + " " + duration.get(i)); //printing out the matches            
    } else {
        System.out.println("Not Tracks Found for " + trackNumber);
    }
```